# How to customize color on item pressed in CustomView in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-drawable

I have an app with ActionBarSherlock with custom view, the view have some clickable linear layout, but they're not responding visually to tapping/clicking.
The custom view is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_button_background_drawable"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:id="@+id/decrease_fontsize"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:clickable="true"            
            android:text="-A"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

with the following drawable: (toolbar_button_background_drawable.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hover" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hover" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```

**hover.9.png** is just a background...

but when I tap on this text, the onclick listener is triggered but visually the LinearLayout is not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to a view, the view gets its drawable state (focused, pressed, etc.) from its direct parent rather than from itself. So the `parent Layout` should be `clickable`.

Just add `android:clickable="true"` to the `parent layout` of the inner `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Doesn't work, I tried all combinations like that, removing clickable=true from child, adding it to child and parent, duplicating state for child only, child and parent, none ... but it looks like something something from the ABS is forcing the styles